# proper way to overwrite debian kernel modules

Tags: debian, package-management, kernel-modules

I just downloaded and compiled `tg3.ko` kernel module. Where should I put it on a Debian system? There is one in `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-xen-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/tg3.ko` already.

Ideally, I would like to leave the original one where it is, and "bump the priority" for mine. So if mine doesn't get loaded or disappears, the original is still there as a fallback.

The only way I know to do it is `dpkg-divert`, but I feel a slight shiver in my stomach when I use it. It is especially scary to do it on a server, with the network module. :)

Comment: You don't say what the motivation for doing this is. Why not use the module that is already on the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your module in `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-xen-amd64/updates/` (make the directory if it doesn't exist) and re-run `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64` (or just run `depmod` if you know how).  Check that the new driver is found with `modprobe -l tg3`.

Read `man 5 depmod.conf` for more details.

Comment: you can then use "fpm" to create nice packages...

works like a charm